# Pandas set column values as row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {"Client" : ["Alice", "Nan", "Nan", "Mallory", "Nan" , "Bob"] , 
    "Product" : ["A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B"] } )
```

And I would like to reach a result like this:

```
Alice   A, B, C
Mallory B, C
Bob     B
```

Does anyone know how to do this using python 3?

Comment: An example of the dataframe you are working with will be helpful. I think pandas transpose might help you here. [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

Comment: you can try `df.T`

Comment: Can you correct the output you would like to see. There is no Robert and Anna in you example.

Comment: Are you trying to link the client names to products. It is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Please provide an appropriate example.

Comment: Sorry! My bad... I'm trying to set the df to after use apyori(apriori) library. And then get a association rule...thats mu goal.

Comment: @Mâncio It is still not clear how you arrive at (A,B,C) for Alice, and (B,C) for Mallory.  There is insufficient information in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `agg` function to `join` items after grouping

With pandas 0.25+

```
df = df.replace("Nan",np.NaN).ffill()
df.groupby('Client', sort=False)['Product'].agg(Product=('Product',','.join)).reset_index()
```

With pandas below 0.25

```
df=df.replace("Nan",np.NaN).ffill()
df.groupby('Client', sort=False)['Product'].agg([('Product', ','.join)]).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    Client  Product
0   Alice   A,B,C
1   Mallory B,C
2   Bob     B
```

Comment: `df.replace("Nan",np.NaN).ffill()` to save one line.

Comment: Even through reassignment? `df=df.replace("Nan",np.NaN).ffill()`?

Comment: @HenryYik. Yes. Error is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ffill'`

Comment: Thats weird. It looks like a `inplace` has been mixed in between - oh well.

Comment: @HenryYik. You are right, `inplace` in between was causing the problems. Your suggestion works. I have updated the code. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice solution. But it gave me a error msg. Do you know why?
TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_or_funcs'

Comment: @Mâncio If you are using pandas below 0.25, use the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the output from a groupby operation (where the "Nan"'s where were the data were)  You will need to put it back to that groupby status to do anything useful with it.

first turn string "Nan"'s to actual NaN's.

```
import numpy as np
df.replace("Nan", np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

then ffill can work.

```
df.ffill(axis=0, inplace=True)
```

then to get the format of the output:  (here is where the magic happens)

```
for group, data in df.groupby(df.Client): 
    print(group, data.Product.tolist())

Alice ['A', 'B', 'C']
Bob ['B']
Mallory ['B', 'C']
```

I'll leave as homework dealing with f string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame( {"Client" : ["Alice", "Nan", "Nan", "Mallory", "Nan" , "Bob"] , 
    "Product" : ["A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B"] } )

last_client = None
data = defaultdict(list)
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    # id hazard a guess you want np.nan not the string compare here
    if row.Client != last_client and row.Client != "Nan":
        last_client = row.Client
    data[last_client].append(row.Product)

print(data)
```

> defaultdict(, {'Alice': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Mallory': ['B', 'C'], 'Bob': ['B']})